# Testrail API to download Suite attachment

Tags: testrail

I trying to use Testrail API. I managed to successfully download attachments from test Cases, but I see no specifications for downloading attachments from Suites and Sections:
https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/attachments/

Is there a way to do it using the regular API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I communicated with gurock. There is no public API, they created feature request, no ETA though.